# JSONPath to get multiple values

Tags: json, splunk, jsonpath

Let's assume that we have the below code

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": "task_1",
      "name": "task_1_name",
      "assignees": [
        {
          "id": "assignee_1",
          "name": "assignee_1_name"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "task_2",
      "name": "task_2_name",
      "assignees": [
        {
          "id": "assignee_2",
          "name": "assignee_2_name"
        },
        {
          "id": "assignee_3",
          "name": "assignee_3_name"
        }
```

what I want is to get the results from id AND from the name

by using the below I get only the id:

$.tasks[*].assignees[*].id

```
[
  "assignee_1",
  "assignee_2",
  "assignee_3"
]
```

So I want to have something like

```
[
  "assignee_1",
  "assignee_1_name",
  "assignee_2",
  "assignee_2_name",
  "assignee_3"
  "assignee_3_name",
]
```

Thank you

Comment: What version of Splunk is this? What have you tried? What error(s) have you received?

Comment: latest version. 9.0.2  as I mentioned I have tried the jsonpath   ->  $.tasks[].assignees[].id      I have tried a few things at jsonpath.com but I don;t have much of knowledge with json

Comment: What have you tried *in Splunk* so far? Or is this a jsonpath.com error?

Comment: I haven't tried something else in Splunk.  whatever I see at  jsonpath.com I can see it at Splunk add-on builder

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Have you ingested the data into Splunk? How are you ingesting it? Have you configured your props.conf and transforms.conf appropriately?

Comment: I am reading the API through the Splunk add-on builder. In the step "Define the data input" there is the option to "Event extraction settings". Through the json path you can select how to break the json to events. So for the moment I know how to extract only one value. I want to extract more values.  e.g. as I mentioned previously   "assignee_1",
 "assignee_1_name",   e.g. https://www.splunk.com/content/dam/splunk-blogs/images/2017/02/Screen-Shot-2017-02-20-at-10.17.35-PM.png

Answer (score 0):

This works on https://jsonpath.com:

```
$.tasks.*.assignees.*.[id,name]
```

Answer (score 0):

you may not be able to do this using single json path, but try this

```
| rename tasks{}.assignees{}.id  as x
| rename tasks{}.assignees{}.name  as y
| eval z=mvzip(x, y)
| table z
| mvexpand z
| eval z = split(z, ",")
| mvexpand z
```